# What does this note in my main panel mean and does it mean it's not okay to use 10/3 to wire my shed with a 30 amp double pole to a 20amp double pole

Tags: electrical-panel

https://photos.app.goo.gl/CeL26aLCWP25XBa77 link will take you to the photo of my panel only way it would let me post it. But I'm mainly trying to figure out if my set up is safe or not I have a 30amp double pole in my outside panel next to the meter feeding 100+' of 10/3 UF that's powering my shed via a 70amp panel with a double pole 20amp breaker with only one side wired so the red wire in the UF cable is capped off

Comment: Most /3 cables are four wires.  Two hots, one neutral and one ground which is not counted.

Comment: Reading the other question, the four wire requirement is only for 240 volts circuits.  For 120 volts only /2 or two wire plus ground is okay.  240v is two hots, 120v is only one hot and neutral.

Comment: I know I only used 10/3 in case I ever needed to run 240 like my 100 gal 6hp compressor

Answer (score 3):

That label doesn't have any bearing on your question.

You **always** need to run 4-wire feeder to a subpanel. They finally banned the last 3-wire feeders in 2008 because of the fatalities.  When you combine neutral and ground, it's not ground anymore, it's neutral. But when neutral breaks, it becomes hot.

In fact, that's *why* your main panel has that label.  It's actually a subpanel.

Before you rush out and buy 10/3 copper, please go price 6-6-6-6 and 2-2-2-4 aluminum USE or MH feeder.  It's less or not a lot more money, and it's 50A or 90A instead of 30A.

Note that NM "Romex" is not allowed outdoors or underground in any case.

Comment: It's already set up sadly I do wish I had went a different route with my choice of wire considering I got 150$ worth of 10/3 UF and can only run either one 20 amp circuit or two 15s or one 240 plug much regret 
considering I need to be able to run a compressor off 240 plus still have at least 1 20 amp circuit to work out of my shed as planned

Comment: Well if you want to put a proper 240V subpanel in there you can put that red wire to good use.  You should be able to run a fair bunch of stuff, probably that compressor as well as a 20A circuit on each leg.  If you're not tracking with all that, here .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4

Comment: Okay so basically if I were to put it to use I could just connect the red wire to the other entry point on the double pole 20 amp and connect my 120 circuit but not to the  second hot / (red wires side) then hard wire my compressor using both hots and a ground and a neutral if needed for some odd reason. Did I get that right?

Comment: @ChasePrice Yeah, on the 10/3 feeder, black and red to the supply breaker (might as well make that 30A/2-pole, the two handles must be factory-tied, a 1 inch wide "tandem" with independent handles is the wrong thing!!!!!!) ... and then on the subpanel, black and red to the two hot lugs.  You should hav 240V across them.  Then you can add breakers in the subpanel to power any circuits you want. If you need a bigger subpanel, get one - they're cheap.